# Categories in custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, archives

I'm having some custom post type but I want to add categories for it. Not for the URL(-structure) but for an archive page, which shows every category after each other. So the items are organized. Anyway to do this or isn't this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use builtin WordPress categories, while calling [register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function with `taxonomies` parameter set to `category`

If you want to create a custom category, then use [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function to register a brand new taxonomy with second parameter to be your custom post type name and pass it taxonomy name to `register_post_type` as explained above.

A sample would look something like this

```
$args = array(
    'label' => __( 'Book' ),
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'taxonomies' => array('language'),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 

  register_taxonomy(
        'language',
        'book',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Language' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'language' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
  register_post_type( 'book', $args );
```

Comment: Anyway to get the category? `$categories =   get_categories($cat_args);` just gets the normal post categories.

Comment: Yes, `get_terms( 'language', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );` if you meant category by your custom taxonomy.

Comment: And last one: posting the name? :)

Comment: I dont get what you mean by "posting the name". p.s You should be searching a little bit before asking on SO.